# JXTA client - server

Tags: java, jxta

I would like to implement a client-server architecture using JXTA. Also the configuration of the server part will be 3 - tier. Does anyone know a good place to get this project started?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2):

JXTA deals with p2p connectivity. This is the opposite of client-server approach.

From what I understand, you want to create a p2p network composed out of 2 nodes. 
You can reach the site of JXSE (Java implementation of JXTA protocol) at http://jxse.kenai.com/Tutorials/Tutorials.html

Also, as far as I know, Oracle dropped its support for the JXTA project and the community intends to move it to Apache Software Foundation under the name Chaupal (there is a project on Google Code under this name: http://code.google.com/p/chaupal/).

I used JXTA for a personal project and it proved quite a beast (difficult to use and lots of bugs). I managed to do a simple p2p network. That was version 2.5. 
Now it is 2.7 and I read it has improved. I couldn't find any tutorials for 2.7 though...

Comment: Actually I discovered that JXTA is dificult to use but I still need it for a project at school. What I want to create is a client-server with 2 clients and 3 servers. The tutorials are few and the code is very difficult to read, that's why I hopped someone would help me.

Comment: I would recommend using the JXTA forum: http://www.java.net/forums/jxta/jxta-community-forum. Also, there is a book by Jerome Verstrynge called Practical JXTA 2. It is freely available at http://www.scribd.com/doc/47538921/Practical-JXTA-II. If you have time, I would recommend it. If what you are doing doesn't need all the protocol stack from JXTA (peer groups, rendezvous, nat traversal & stuff) you can try to implement your own small protocol.  You might be surprised that you are faster this way. It depends on what you want.